# 'tail' on an unindexed tale

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a large **unindexed** table in a staging database and want to get a feel for the data. I can look at the top few rows using a limit clause. I can look at the last few, too using:

```
set @n = (select count(*) from my_table) ; -- a big number
select * from my_table limit @n-10, n; -- takes a while
```

Is there a **quick** way to look at the last few rows in an unindexed InnoDB table- equivalent to 'tail' on a file? I imagine 'limit 10' on an unindexed table gets the first 10 rows physically stored in practice (but I shouldn't rely on that)? Or do you have another favourite way to sample rows?

Comment: And the reason you can't add index to this table is: ...?

Comment: you have to order you table somehow, otherwise there are no guarantees that you will get the last records

Comment: I was looking at it because it had more rows than the production version - I wanted a quick idea of why (more data? duplicates?); In this case, the first few rows were in production, the last few weren't, and the primary key was unchanged by the new data. Sometimes it's useful to get a feel for data before adding indexes; for example it would be annoynig to wait ages for a unique index to build only to have it fail because the last few rows are obvious dups; if I don't expect dups, an unique index is a good proof. I wondered if there was a better way.

Comment: There is no such thing as first or last row in a table. You can order your result set with `ORDER BY`, and if you want the last X rows you can order the rows in reverse and add `LIMIT X`.

Comment: Vatalev - true in principle but not I think in practice. By observation, unindexed tables behave a little like files with the new stuff at the end (or perhaps in gaps) - and that's good enough for getting a feel for the data.